# Searching a Value across an entire spreadsheet

Tags: excel, match, lookup, vlookup

I have an excel spreadsheet and in one column (lets call it org numbers) of one sheet i have a list of values.  On another tab i have these values scattered between A1:AX281.

I am trying to do a match/lookup/count to ensure the positions i have between A1:AX281 match the values i have in the org numbers sheet.  I have searched this for a while now and haven't found something to an exact match.  i have tried using certain formulas but i wonder if merged cells and formulas in these cells affect my result?

Comment: I have tried a Vlookup, a Match, a countif and i keep getting either the error Value or the error #N/A

Comment: It is not clear if you are trying to verify the values on Sheet1 exist in the Range A1:AX281 or vice versa. Do you want Column 2 of sheet one to display the cell address from sheet 2 the matching value is found or do you want the value on sheet 2 highlighted indicating it exists on sheet 1?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the cells A1:Ax281 have a matching value in column 1 of sheet one do the following:

1. On sheet three cell a1 add the following formula:

   =Match(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)
2. Copy the formula from A1 to AX1, then from A1:Ax1 to A281:AX281.
3. The result will be a heat map with #N/A's in every cell where the value does not match and a number in ever cell that does.

Alternatively, you can enhance the formula to display the matching value or blank by changing the formula to:

=if(isna(Match(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)),"",Sheet2!a1)

If you want to identify the cells on Sheet 1 not found on sheet 2, copy all the values from sheet 2 into a single column in sheet3 then use the match function to look down the single list.